# How to write values of function to file?

Tags: functions, output-formatting, files-and-directories

For example, say I wanted to plot Sin(x) like this:

```
Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,2 Pi}]
```

But instead of plotting to a graph, I  want to now tabulate the values of Sin[x] to a data file.
How do I achieve this?

**EDIT:** Sorry I wasn't clear enough, I mean plot the x values in one column and the y values in the second column

Comment: Well, that depends: do you want equal spacing of points, or do you want to make use of mathematica's adaptive sampling?

Comment: Just equal spacing for now

Comment: See the update to my question for `{ x, Sin[x] }` values together as per your question update.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First create your points, running from 0 to 2 Pi at intervals of 0.01.

```
points = Table[{x,Sin[x]}, {x, Range[0, 2 \[Pi], .01]}];
```

You can plot them with:

```
ListLinePlot[points]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And export them to a csv file with:

```
Export["points.csv", points]
```

Comment: I think he need something like this:Table[{x,Sin[x]},{x,xmin,xman,dx}]//Transpose

Comment: @yulinlinyu Perhaps, I interpreted the OPs use of "column" to mean that the output file should contain 2 columns. If they export the transposed data it will give them two rows and many columns.

Answer (score 8):

You can select the points from the plot and write it to file with `Export`:

```
pl = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}];
```

The Points are arguments to a `Line` directive in the `Plot` function:

```
Position[pl, Line]
```

output is:    `{{1, 1, 3, 2, 0}}` the zero is the `Head` of the `Line` directive, the points are the argument:

```
points = pl[[1, 1, 3, 2, 1]];
```

Alternatively you can also produce the {x,y} pairs directly:

```
points = Table[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}];
```

Now I use export to write it all to a file

```
Export[< output.file >, points, "Table"]
```

Please note, that there is a typo in your code. You should use square brackets to give function argumens: `Sin[x]` instead of `Sin(x)`

**Edit:**

To get {x,y} pairs from a list of x-positions you can for instance use:

```
xypairs = {#, Sin[#]} & /@ points
```

/@ is a shorthand notation for Map.
To calculate it directly in the Table command replace Sin[x] by {x,Sin[x]}.

Here is another method to get the points directly from the plot using EvaluationMonitor:

```
{pl, points} = 
  Reap[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, Sin[x]}]]];
```

Comment: How do I get the x values in one column and the y values in another column? All I get are the y values

Comment: @Eddy I updated the answer for the {x,y} pairs.

Answer (score 2):

This is to show some of *Mathematica's* other features.

create a list of x values:

```
x = Range[0, 2 Pi, 0.1];
```

create a list of y values:

```
y = Sin @ x;
```

(`Sin` is [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Listable.html); if it were not you would use [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html): `Sin /@ x`.  Also see [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html).)

Put them together:

```
data = {x, y}\[Transpose];
```

The Transpose symbol is entered <kbd>Esc</kbd>`tr`<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

[`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Export.html) `data` in whatever [format](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ImportingAndExporting.html) you desire, e.g.:

```
ExportString["datafile.txt", data, "Table"]
```

Comment: Just a little comment that there's not need to use the transpose superscript symbol there--although it does look nice in a notebook. A straightforward `Transpose[{x,y}]` will produce the same result.